# Conditional Correlation for Stochastic Processes

Tags: probability, analysis, conditional-expectation, martingales

Any help with the following problem will be greatly appreciated.

Two stochastic processes $X_t$ and $Y_t$ are called conditionally uncorrelated given $\mathcal F_t$, if $$E[(X_t - X_s)(Y_t - Y_s)|\mathcal F_s] = 0 \quad \forall\, 0 \leq s < t < \infty $$

Let $X_t$ and $Y_t$ be martingale processes. Show that the processes $Z_t = X_tY_t$ is a martingale if and only if $X_t$ and $Y_t$ are conditionally uncorrelated. Assume that $X_t$, $Y_t$ and $Z_t$ are integrable.

Note: Apparently there is an identity $$E[(X_t - X_s)(Y_t - Y_s)|
\mathcal F_s] = E[X_tY_t - X_sY_s|\mathcal F_s]$$
however I am unsure how to use that in the above proof.

Thank you

Comment: Please share your ideas!

Comment: @Gabriel Thank you for wanting to help! I failed to realize that $E[X_sY_S|\mathcal F_s] = X_sY_s$. It's all good now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, we notice that 
\begin{align}
E[(X_t - X_s)(Y_t - Y_s)|
\mathcal F_s] &= E[X_tY_t - X_tY_s -X_sY_t +\underbrace{X_sY_s}_{\mathcal{F}_s-\text{mesurable}}|\mathcal F_s]\\ 
&= E[X_tY_t|\mathcal F_s] - Y_sE[X_t|\mathcal F_s]  - X_sE[Y_t|\mathcal F_s] + X_sY_s \\
&= E[X_tY_t|\mathcal F_s] - Y_sX_s  - X_sY_s + X_sY_s \\
&=E[X_tY_t-X_sY_s|\mathcal F_s]\tag{1}
\end{align}
The third equality comes from the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are martingales.

Let's do the $\Rightarrow$ first:
Assume that $\lbrace{Z_t\rbrace}_{t\geq0}$ is a martingale. We have: for $s \leq t$
\begin{align}
E[(X_t - X_s)(Y_t - Y_s)|
\mathcal F_s] &= E[X_tY_t - X_sY_s|\mathcal F_s]\\
&= E[X_tY_t |\mathcal F_s]- X_sY_s \\
&= X_sY_s- X_sY_s = 0
\end{align}
The last equality follows from the martingale property.

Now the $\Leftarrow$. We assume that $E[(X_t - X_s)(Y_t - Y_s)|
\mathcal F_s] =0$. Using $(1)$, we have :
\begin{align}
&E[X_tY_t - X_sY_s|\mathcal F_s] =0\\
&\Rightarrow\quad E[X_tY_t|\mathcal F_s] = X_sY_s
\end{align}
Plus, we know that $Z\in L_1$. Therefore, we can conclude that $Z$ is  a martingale.